# CRM retrieve records with Fetchxml on today minus n days

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I need fetchxml condition operator to retrieve all my appointments on today-11 days. I mean if I run my query today(12/04/2018) I want to retrieve my created records on 01/04/2018. If I run on 13/04/2018 - records created on 02/04/2018. Which operator can I use to get what I need?

```
<fetch distinct="false" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0">
  <entity name="appointment">
        <attribute name="subject"/>
        <attribute name="statecode"/>
        <attribute name="scheduledstart"/>
        <attribute name="scheduledend"/>
        <attribute name="createdby"/>
        <attribute name="regardingobjectid"/>
        <attribute name="activityid"/>
        <attribute name="instancetypecode"/>
        <order descending="false" attribute="subject"/>
        <filter type="and">
           <condition attribute="createdon" value="" operator=""/>
       </filter>
 </entity>
```

Comment: You cannot do it directly inside the query. If you're running your fetch in code (for example inside a plugin o in a js), you could calculate the date before the declaration and use it inside the query as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight operator for this. You have to use `eq` operator & calculate the expression (-11) yourself if you are using this fetchxml query in SSRS report `@date`:

```
<condition attribute="new_date" operator="eq" value="@date"></condition>
```

Or calculate in javascript/C# & pass it to `paramDate`, if you are calling this in form script or server code:

```
'<condition attribute="new_date" operator="eq" value="' + paramDate + '"></condition>'
```

Comment: Arun, thank you for your answer. I will consider it in my code

Answer (score 3):

There is no single operator, but you can easily combine two:

```
<filter type="and">
  <condition attribute="createdon" operator="last-x-days" value="11" />
  <condition attribute="createdon" operator="olderthan-x-days" value="10" />
</filter>
```